# Android Specific file title

Tags: android

I have faced with one problem: I tried to put video files with spanish titles(i.e. Puente Hacia **Atrás**) in assets folder and to do a listview to present titles of my videos. But when i try to get assets, convert it to list and get list length than I got 0 result. If I remove this specific spanish char everything is OK(video title is displayed in listview and video can be played). So, that is possible to do that such a title like this will be definable by app? I thought that app works in UTF-8 encoding type.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode is not supported in assets filenames ([see issue here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11368)).

I would suggest you rename your files using ASCII only, and store their "display name" in your `strings.xml`.

UPDATE:

I am afraid there is no way to do a call like getString(R.string. + filenameVar).

What you could do to match the filenames against their display name is use a Map:

```
private Map<String, String> aMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
aMap.put("puente_atras.mp4", getString(R.string.puente_atras));
aMap.put("calle_atras.mp4", getString(R.string.calle_atras));
```

Comment: I see... That`s Bad. In this case, how is possible to compare file name with data from strings.xml?

Comment: But that is possible to do something like this.getString(R.string. + variable) ?